# Hirefire isn't working with Heroku/Delayed Job/Mongoid - latest versions

Tags: heroku, mongoid, delayed-job, hirefire

I am using the [hirefire beta](https://manager.hirefire.io) to manage my mongoid-based DJ queue workers - adding and removing dynos as the queue depth changes.

The problem is that all I get is the error:

```
2013-01-27T23:07:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/hirefire/d98c3c1f840e8b903j3od03kka3f110b1779ccb5/info" for 5.19.20.84 at 2013-01-27 23:07:14 +0000
2013-01-27T23:07:14+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-01-27T23:07:14+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
2013-01-27T23:07:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   config/initializers/hirefire.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My versions:

```
Using rails (3.2.11)
Using delayed_job (3.0.4)
Using delayed_job_mongoid (2.0.0)
Using mongoid (3.0.19)
```

`config/initializers/hirefire.rb`:

```
HireFire::Resource.configure do |config|
  config.dyno(:worker) do
    HireFire::Macro::Delayed::Job.queue
  end
end
```

Any suggestions? I have tried various suggestions I could find, all resulting in various other errors and no progress.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was due to having ActiveRecord still installed, the Mongoid installation has some details on removing ActiveRecord from your app.

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#installation